# Image Repetition from Binary to Cartesian

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'd like to take in an RGB image, find the points in the image that are white, and get the cartesian coordinates of those points in the image. I've gotten most of the way there, but when I try to plot the cartesian coordinates, I get a vertically tiled image (i.e. 5 overlapped copies of what I should see). Anyone know what could be causing this?

[image: Starting Image], [image: Final Image]

Code: (JPG comes in as 2448 x x3264 x 3 uint8)

```
I = imread('IMG_0245.JPG');
imshow(I); % display unaltered image

% Convert image to grayscale
I = rgb2gray(I); 
% Convert image to binary (black/white)
I = im2bw(I, 0.9); 
% Generate cartesian coordinates of image
imageSize = size(I);
[x, y] = meshgrid( 1:imageSize(1), 1:imageSize(2) );
PerspectiveImage = [x(:), y(:), I(:)];

% Get indices of white points only
whiteIndices = find(PerspectiveImage(:,3));
figure; plot( PerspectiveImage(whiteIndices, 1), PerspectiveImage(whiteIndices, 2),'.');
% Flip vertically to correct indexing vs. plotting issue
axis ij
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple.  You're declaring your `meshgrid` wrong.  It should be:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid( 1:imageSize(2), 1:imageSize(1) );
```

The first parameter denotes the **horizontal** extents of the 2D grid, and so you want to make this vary for as many columns as you have.  Similarly, the second parameter denotes the **vertical** extents of the 2D grid, and so you want to make this for as many rows as you have.

I had to pre-process some of your image to get some good results because your original image had a large white border surrounding the image.  I had to remove this border by removing all pure white pixels.  I also read in the image directly from StackOverflow:

```
I = imread('http://s7.postimg.org/ovb53w4ff/Track_example.jpg');
mask = all(I == 255, 3);
I = bsxfun(@times, I, uint8(~mask));
```

This was the image I get after doing my pre-processing:

[image]

Once I do this and change your `meshgrid` call, I get this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the white border - that appeared as a result of saving a Matlab figure as a jpg. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @lg22woo I figured :) it happens when you natively save figures in MATLAB.  BTW, I'd recommend you use the `export_fig` tool on MATLAB FileExchange.  Much better way of saving figures to disk: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig - I've been using it for years!